# Java code unexpectedly appending "&#13" to line endings

Tags: java, windows, ascii, windows-server-2008, newline

Our code is unexpectedly appending `&#13` to the end of the lines created by the following routine:

```
public String getNotation(ClientMessage TransactionMessage) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    sb.append(getNotationTitle(TransactionMessage));
    sb.append(lineSeparator);
    sb.append(lineSeparator);
```

The "line.separator" seems to be getting translated to the string `&#13` only when the code is run on a Windows Server 2008 box. It runs fine when we run the same on Windows 7 or UNIX.

Has any one encountered this issue, and if so is there any logical explanation and a solution to correct this?

Comment: did you check the output in a different editor? It might be an editor issue at times.

Comment: It runs fine when we check in an editor, when the code is executed in the actual server that is the time it produces this issue.

Comment: Do you get `&#13` at every line termination or only at the end of the file? Does it appear in an editor? What charset are you using to write to the file and read from it?

Comment: It happens for every line.

Comment: @gagneet any updates on this question? what did the issue end up being?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP (and other textual internet protocols) mandate the use of ASCII `CR+LF` for line break sequences - `CR` being the "carriage return" character (`\r`) and `LF` being the "line feed" character (`\n`).

This escape sequence - `\r\n` - is also the file separator used on Windows systems, and thus is what gets returned by your call to `System.getProperty("line.separator")` and then gets appended by your call to `sb.append(lineSeparator)` to the output string. This is happening both in your tests and when "the code is executed on the actual server" - in both instances (I presume), the code is being *executed* on your windows server, and thus the same string generated.

This sequence is not being translated to `&#13`, as you suggest. If it was, then your entire output would appear on a single line, with `&#13` inserted where newlines are expected. However, it doesn't sound like that's the case - it sounds like you're getting the line breaks where you expect them but with an unexpected `&#13` at the end of each line.

This makes sense when we recognize that a lone `\n` is sufficient to represent a line break in most programming languages and environments, and that **13 is the decimal representation of the carriage return character**

I presume that your tests are displaying the strings generated in raw string form (perhaps simply by a call to `println(sb.toString())`, in which case the `\r\n` is being interpreted and displayed as you expect it to be.

I also presume that your `TransactionMessage` class is transmitting messages not as raw strings but rather as HTML, because `&#13` would be the HTML entity code for the decimal representation of the carriage return character.

I can't tell you exactly why (at least without knowing more about your particular situation), but for some reason the LR character is being converted to its decimal representation, and your chosen method for displaying the resultant string on the client doesn't recognize that representation as a control character and therefore is displaying it as the literal `&#13` immediately preceding the `\n`, which *is* being interpreted as an escape.

*(unrelated side note: Since Java 7, you can use* `System.lineSeparator()` *in place of* `System.getProperty("line.separator")`)

Comment: Thanks for this answer @drewmore. I think this does provide me answers to what I need to start looking for, instead of concentrating on this piece of code.

Comment: you're welcome @gagneet! let me know how it goes - most of this answer was just me reasoning on the fly, I'm curious to see what I was wrong and right about.

Comment: @gagneet - what ended up happening with this problem?